# WHMCS Domain/TLD setup

Tags: whmcs

I have hit past 165 domains entered with pricing, now it wont let me add anymore domains. Whats is a work around for this or what could be the issue? Thanks (Also checked the WHMCS logs and no records of any errors)

Answer (score 2):

WHMCS has no 'limit' to the number of TLDs

If you've reached a level where you cannot add any more then that will be a configuration issue with your server/apache/php - some sort of setting/limit on form submits - check your server logs.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The error log showed PHP Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. The solution was to modify the max_input_vars value in php.ini. I can now add the TLDs.

Comment: Don't add a signature to your posts, especially not if it contains links. This might lead to you getting banned because of spamming.